# Как изменить свойства объекта из App - Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

В app у меня есть таймер. Когда он срабатывает мне необходимо, находясь на другой форме, сделать появление кнопки без перезагрузки страницы. Подскажите, как это сделать? Я пробовал объявить глобальные ресурсы и пробовать их изменять (в свойстве кнопки IsVisible поместил DynamicResource resource), но после изменения значений глобальных ресурсов появление не происходит и приложение ломается( исчезает возможность навигации и тп). Помогите...

Answer (score 0):

Оттолкнитесь от того, что таймер вызывает событие.

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent; //<- событие
```

если у события есть подписчики, то они смогут на это событие среагировать.

Ваше решение - подпишитесь на это событие в нужной форме и обновите статус IsVisible.